# Delete a query with analytic function

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, sql-delete, analytic-functions

Delete the records that have the minimum of records,  I have 2 tables person (id, otherID) otherID is a reference of an other person.id and film (id, country, personID) where personID is a foreign key of person.id

I want to delete all the records in film table that have the minimum of records relative to personID and country.  For example:

```
Person(1, 2)
Person(2, 2)
Person(3, 2)
Film(1, fr, 1)
Film(2, uk, 1)
Film(3, fr, 2)
Film(4, fr, 3)
Film(5, usa, 1)
Film(6, fr, 1)
```

I have to remove 
    Film(3, fr, 2)
Person(1, 2 )->because count of person 1 in the country fr, 2, is upper then the count of other person 2 (otherID column) in the same country 'fr',1.

Person(2, 2) nothing to remove

Person(3, 2) delete one of the records Film(3, fr, 2) or Film(4, fr, 3) because both have fr as country and count = 1 but as the record Film(3, fr, 2) is deleted before so Film(4, fr, 3) have to be kept.

where count = select count(*) over (partition by film.personID, film.country) from film

and keep

```
Film(1, fr, 1)
Film(2, uk, 1)
Film(4, fr, 3)
Film(5, usa, 1)
Film(6, fr, 1)
```

Actually for each record in person table we ll look for:

a = select count(*) over (partition person.id,film.country)

b = select count(*) over (partition person.otherID,film.country)

The same film.country for both a and b and then delete the record which have min(a,b)

Comment: Could you please take some time in writing your question? It should contain as a minimum a _clear_ description of [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) when attempting solve your query.

Comment: @R Vive L ol: Agreed with Ben ,i am not getting how your getting the count ?,please make it clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can write a query that either identifies the rows that are to be deleted *or* identifies the rows that are not to be deleted, and which ideally returns a set of ROWID's, then you can simply:

```
Delete from my table where rowid in ( ...);
```

or

```
Delete from my table where rowid not in ( ...);
```